# adding to a list from within method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to Asp.net and C#, I am trying to log changes made to a directory. The problem I am running into is that from within my method which picks up changes made to a directory, I am unable to add the information (in the form of a string) to a list, listbox, or anything outside the method at all.

Here is the method that picks up directory changes:

```
protected void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

    if (!m_bDirty)
    {

        m_Sb.Clear();

        m_Sb.Append(e.FullPath);
        m_Sb.Append(" ");
        m_Sb.Append(e.ChangeType.ToString());
        m_Sb.Append("    ");
        m_Sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        m_bDirty = true;
        test.Add(m_Sb.ToString());
```

Here are my variables outside the method:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher;
private bool m_bDirty;
private StringBuilder m_Sb = new StringBuilder();
private List<String> test = new List<String>();
```

My problem is that when I try to pull information from the list(test) outside the OnChanged method, there is nothing there.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside" the OnChange method? Have you tried making that variable protected instead of private?

Comment: I mean anything outside the OnChange method. For instance, if I attempt to add to the ListBox on the page from the OnChange method nothing happens. If I try to add to the list declared outside the class, nothing is there. and yes I have tried protected instead of private. no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a postback occurs on the page, your List test will be reinitialized as a new List, which will clear any data it may have had.

You can instead declare it as a static field, then initialize it during a page

```
private static List<string> test;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    test = test ?? new List<string>();
    // ... additional initalization
}
```

You can then clear the list by setting it back to null after it's handled by your other method.

Comment: You shouldn't use static data in a web application.

Comment: @Maarten: I agree, ideally it should be stateless. With web forms it's probably better stored as a session variable. This was just a quick solution that worked for the use case without requiring a lot of alterations to the current code.